# Manually wake up epoll_wait through gdb?

Tags: linux, gdb, epoll, systems-programming

I have a program stuck in epoll_wait for an unknown reason (the timeout didn't kick in). Is there a way to force epoll_wait to return using gdb?

Note that I can't stop / recompile the program - I actually need to unstick this instance of the program

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to write something in fd that `epoll_wait` is waiting from gdb prompt (assuming `epoll_wait` is waiting for this type of events):

```
(gdb) call write(fd, "42", 3)
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I'm getting EINVAL back. I also tried send() without success. I don't know the code so I don't really what it's waiting for